# Kendo UI Core - Bootstrap Stylesheets

Tags: kendo-ui

I downloaded Kendo UI Core from Telerik website, and I want to make use of the Boostrap theme for my widgets, but however theres three bootstrap stylesheets to choose from: `kendo.bootstrap.min.css`, `kendo.common-bootstrap.core.min.css` and `kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css`. I'll be using datepicker, input masks and dropdowns. Which one should I use? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that `kendo.common-bootstrap.core.min` only includes styling for the free widgets (Kendo UI Core) and `kendo.common-bootstrap.min` includes styling for all the free widgets and the paid widgets (Kendo UI Pro).

If you aren't using any of the "Pro" widgets, then you could use the `.core.` file.

---

You also need to add the kendo bootstrap theme.

Overall, you should have something like:

```
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="kendo.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Those 3 files are:

1. Actual bootstrap styling.
2. Kendo Bootstrap sizing and layout
3. Kendo Bootstrap theme

Comment: I tried to use it as you say, and it's not working. Theres is another file that I should load? For instance I see on their website, they use 'kendo.common.css' and 'kendo.boostrap.css'